# SQL - How to calculate column value and join with another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

As I am not good with MySQL query's so I wish someone help me for creating this kind of sql query.

I having two MySQL tables which is describe bellow:

```
Table Name: rating
-------------------
property_id   user_id   area_rate_count   safety_rate_count   friendly_rate_count   walkability_rate_count
4             28        1                 1                   1                     2
5             38        2                 3                   4                     1
5             40        2                 2                   3                     1
6             40        2                 3                   1                     4
10            43        2                 2                   3                     1  

Table Name: listing
-------------------
property_id   title
4             Sample 1
5             Sample 2
6             Sample 3
10            Sample 4
11            Sample 5
12            Sample 6
```

Now first I want to sum each column and divide. (area_rate_count, safety_rate_count, friendly_rate_count, walkability_rate_count). For example In `property_id:5` having two times so first calculate column sum and divide by 2.

**After calculation we will get this output:**

```
Table Name: rating (After Calculation)
--------------------------------------
property_id   rate
4             5
5             9 (Divided by 2 because this property_id is two times in table)
6             10
10            8
```

And Finally I want join this result to my `listing` table and result looks something like this:

```
Table Name: listing
-------------------
property_id   title         rate
4             Sample 1      5
5             Sample 2      9 (Divided by 2 becouse property_id is two times in table)
6             Sample 3      10
10            Sample 4      8
11            Sample 5      0
12            Sample 6      0
```

Thanks.

Comment: What if you decide to add more rates? What happens then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `avg()` aggregation function along with a `join`:

```
select l.property_id, l.title,
       coalesce(avg(area_rate_count + safety_rate_count + friendly_rate_count + walkability_rate_count
          ), 0) as rate
from listing l left outer join
     property_id p
     on l.property_id = p.property_id
group by l.property_id, l.title ;
```

Comment: I am trying you query but where is the `rating` table?

Comment: I think it was just a typo, change `left outer join property_id p` to `left outer join rating p`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping me but I have updated my question so can you please check once again. Sorry for changing in my question.

Comment: @Mr.Happy . . . You just have to add `coalesce()` to get `0` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Hi Now your query is perfect but When I am trying to sorting `rate` in phpmyadmin not working. I am thing that number has decimal thats why not working??

Comment: Hey one more question what if I want all `listing` table files without writing like this `l.property_id, l.title,`. Is it possible? I want like `*` in select query.

Comment: @Mr.Happy . . . You can write `l.*`.  This is reasonable if `l.property_id` has no duplicates in the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Working perfect. Thanks for your great support :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am trying to add this where statment but not getting error `WHERE l.approved = 1`? How to add in this query?

Comment: @Mr.Happy . . . That should work if you put it between the `from` and `group by` clauses.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okay. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right I think you need this:

```
select l.property_id, l.title, coalesce(r.ssum/if(r.ct=0,1,r.ct), 0) as rate
  from listing l LEFT JOIN
       (select property_id,
               sum(area_rate_count+safety_rate_count
                     +friendly_rate_count+walkability_rate_count) ssum,
               count(*) ct
          from rating 
         group by property_id ) r 
       ON l.property_id = r.property_id
  order by l.property_id
```

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/589d6/5

**Edit**

As OP asked on the comments that he wants all columns from `listing` here is what he want:

```
select l.*, coalesce(r.ssum/if(r.ct=0,1,r.ct), 0) as rate
  from listing l LEFT JOIN
       (select property_id,
               sum(area_rate_count+safety_rate_count
                     +friendly_rate_count+walkability_rate_count) ssum,
               count(*) ct
          from rating 
         group by property_id ) r 
       ON l.property_id = r.property_id
  order by l.property_id
```

Comment: Hi. Your query is good but I have updated my question so can you please check once again. Sorry for changing in my question.

Comment: I've added the coalesce function to return 0 on null values.

Comment: Yes but need small help I don't know is it possible or not but I want all fields from listing and I don't want to write one by one like this `l.property_id, l.title,`. I want to use `*`. Is it possible with listing table??

Comment: Yes, just change `l.property_id, l.title,` to `l.*, ` and leave the coalesce part.

Comment: I've added on the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Happy If the answer (OR ANY OTHER) solved your problem, you should   consider in accept it as correct answer, so people with same problem will be directed to a proper solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
  temp_table ( INDEX(col_2) ) 
ENGINE=MyISAM 
 AS (
    SELECT
    property_id,
    AVG(area_rate_count) as area_rate_count, 
    AVG(safety_rate_count) as safety_rate_count, 
    AVG(friendly_rate_count) as friendly_rate_count, 
    AVG(walkability_rate_count) as walkability_rate_count
    FROM rating
    GROUP BY property_id
)

SELECT * FROM listing L
JOIN temp_table T
ON L.property_id = T.property_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below statement to get distinct property_id with its own rate

```
 select property_id, sum(separaterating)/count(property_id) from (
select property_id,sum(area_rate_count  , safety_rate_count  , friendly_rate_count  , walkability_rate_count) as separaterating from rating group by property_id  AS temp ) group by
```

property_id

you can then join with the other table to get the final result as below

```
 select * from (  select property_id, sum(separaterating)/count(property_id) from (
select property_id,sum(area_rate_count  , safety_rate_count  , friendly_rate_count  , walkability_rate_count) as separaterating from rating group by property_id  AS temp ) group by
```

property_id) AS A inner join listing AS B on A.property_id = B.property_id

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    select a.prop_id as property_id,  l.title,  a.allratings / b.numberofreviews as rate
    from 
    (
        select property_id as prop_id, SUM(coalesce(area_rate_count,0)  + coalesce(safety_rate_count,0) + coalesce(friendly_rate_count,0) + coalesce(walkability_rate_count,0))  as allratings
        from rating
        group by property_id
        ) a inner join 
          (
            select property_id, count(distinct user_id) as numberofreviews
            from rating
            group by property_id
        ) b on a.property_id = b.property_id
        inner join listing  l on a.property_id = l.property_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query

`select ls.property_id,ls.title,inr.rate from listing as ls
left join
(select r.property_id as pid,r.rate/r.cnt as rate from 
(select property_id,user_id,(area_rate_count+safefty_rate_count+friendly_rate_count+walkability_rate_count) as rate,count(*) as cnt from rating group by property_id) as r) as inr on inr.pid=ls.property_id`

Comment: try this query.. i think this one help you.

Comment: getting this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'r1 ) as inr on inr.pid=ls.property_id LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1`

Comment: ohh sorry my mistake wait i change query

Comment: Now Try.. i think now it will help you

Comment: Yes but getting only one result :(

Comment: What happen ... query helpful for you or not?